# Android Studio and Visual Studio Emulator for Android debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, emulation

Is it possible to connect the shiny Visual Studio Emulator for Android installed with Visual Studio 2015 RC to Android Studio?

It is not showing in Run/Debug:

[image]

[SOLVED]

Found the address of the emulator:

[image]

then connected to it using adb connect

[image]

and voila:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, worked for me

Comment: I request you to please add the solution that you found as an answer in this thread. That ways it will be more helpful and easy to spot for future readers. It will also give the users a chance to upvote your answer if they find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the answer from above for easy spotting for readers:

Find the address of the emulator:

[image]

then connected to it using adb connect

[image]

and voila:

[image]